# Why does my mouse hovering randomly stop working in OSX?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, logitech-mouse

I have a Logitech wireless mouse for use with my MacBook (2.5 years old), running Snow Leopard in external monitor/keyboard/mouse mode. For whatever reason, the mouse hovering (in menus, dock, hot corners, etc) stops working.  Clicking will still work.

I tried installing the drivers from Logitech's site, but this did not fix the problem. Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be experiencing interference in the wireless frequency (most likely 2.4GHZ).  If you also use wireless networking, try configuring your router to use another channel.

Other points of failure might be the battery in the mouse (try changing it), or just the mouse hardware aging (get a new mouse).

If you can borrow another wireless mouse from a friend, this might help you figure out if the problem is interference or something else.